# Show multiple vales as 'selected' in Select2 dropdownlist using PHP

Tags: php, dropdown, jquery-select2

In one of the webpage I have a form where I have used Select2 dropdownlist(multi-value select box) as shown below:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" name="inputRCCC[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

Now in 'Edit mode' I want to show some values as 'Selected' for which I have used the following code which sadly does not work as intended.

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" name="inputRCCC[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Red"<?=$rCropsAry[0]=='Red'?' selected="selected"':'';?>>Red</option>
    <option value="Blue"<?=$rCropsAry[0]=='Blue'?' selected="selected"':'';?>>Blue</option>
    <option value="Green"<?=$rCropsAry[0]=='Green'?' selected="selected"':'';?>>Green</option>
    <option value="Yellow"<?=$rCropsAry[0]=='Yellow'?' selected="selected"':'';?>>Yellow</option>
</select>
```

The above code is not working, i.e. dropdownlist do not show any values as selected. Hope I have made myself clear. Please help with some codes.

Comment: You could take a look at this link: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options

Comment: Try adding a space between `value="Red"` and `<?=$rCropsAry[0]=='Red'?' selected="selected"`

Comment: Added space but still it does not work :(

Comment: @Klediooo I want to do using PHP, can it be done?

Comment: You could use your PHP variables in your javascript method. I don't know, if its possible with only php.